# inetd analog for Windows

Tags: sockets, daemon

Need a better analog of inetd daemon for Windows.
Currently using http://sourceforge.net/projects/winetd/, but it's outdated with bugs present.

Please recommend any better solutions for running your own PHP, Python, Perl - based daemons on Windows.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) has inetd, and you could configure that to launch your code. Once you get the Cygwin base install could also use Cygwin perl/php/python, even bash to be a net daemon.

2) you could run any of these under apache, which is the most common way of running net code for most of these scripts. You'd have to be ok with wrapping your data in HTTP, but it also gives you a lot, including config, process management, logging, etc.

3) Any of these scripting languages can create a listen socket and serve code that way. You could use any scheduler to start the script to be a daemon on it's own.

Any particular reason why you're trying inetd and not run under apache?

The inetd model was for infrequent, long run connections like telnet. If that's your model, then fine. But if it's many short run connections, apache may be a better controller for you.

Comment: There are many reasons why I don't wanna use 2) and 3), including the ones you've mentioned. I'm interested in 1), so here is my question - will this cygwin configuration communicate properly with my current Windows 7 environment and network generally. Specifically: Can it run as a service with inetd so my php/python  scripts can communicate with the database server located on the same network? Thanks.

Comment: @Radio At it's base, Cygwin is just a DLL that gives a UNIX like API on Windows. There's nothing preventing a program communicating with anything.